# IBM DSX Desktop - Support for Flows

Tags: docker, data-science-experience

I have a fully operational DSX Desktop 12 implementation and a POWER AI setup. I see that Flows requires a Spark instance, an Object Storage instance and a Machine Learning instance to execute. I am looking for advice on how to create such an environment with IBM DSX Desktop using VirtualBox or Docker. Many thanks in anticipation - Keith

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Flows on DSX Desktop.